# how to: update a users permissions to send mesages in a text channel after joining voice

Tags: discord.js

Im attempting to make a bot updatre permissions for a member to gain access to a text channel after joining a voice channel. I had found a previous solution however I had no luck with it.

```
const pairs = require('./channelPairs.json');
  client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let oldID;
  let newID;
  if (oldMember.voiceChannel) oldID = oldMember.voiceChannel.id;
  if (newMember.voiceChannel) newID = newMember.voiceChannel.id;

for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
  const textChannel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.get(pairs[i].text);
  if (!textChannel) {
  console.log('Invalid text channel ID in json.');
  continue;
}

const vcID = pairs[i].voice;

if (oldID !== vcID && newID === vcID) {          // Joined the voice channel.
  textChannel.overwritePermissions(newMember, {
    VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
    SEND_MESSAGES: true
  }).catch(console.error);
} else if (oldID === vcID && newID !== vcID) {   // Left the voice channel.
  textChannel.overwritePermissions(newMember, {
    VIEW_CHANNEL: null,
    SEND_MESSAGES: null
  }).catch(console.error);
 }
}
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am not getting any errors however the text channel isnt updating permissions for the users.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Are you getting an error? Is the bot not reaching that code?

Comment: updated it to inlcude the issue im having